# Exponentiation Error "TypeError: Type rational_const"

Tags: solidity

I can not get the answer of the expression

```
int256 test2 = ((0.0035+1)**120)*(10**18);
```

> TypeError: Type rational_const 2021...(389 digits omitted)...2001 /
>   1329...(371 digits omitted)...0000 is not implicitly convertible to expected type int256. Try converting to type ufixed256x58 or use an
>   explicit conversion.

```
int256 test2 = ((0.0035+1)**4)*(10**18);
```

> This expression does not give an error

How can I solve such an expression with the help of Solidity?

```
int256 test2 = ((0.0035+1)**120)*(10**18);
```

Comment: The issue is caused because the result is not an integer (with 4 as exponent it is an integer). Either calculate the result externally to solidity and use the result directly or try to convince solidity developers to implement conversion from rationals to int256.